# sufficient conditions for tightness of a sequence of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory

I am interested in knowing sufficient conditions for tightness of a sequence of probability measures other than the one mentioned in [Condition implying tightness of sequence of probability measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142631/condition-implying-tightness-of-sequence-of-probability-measures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in the linked thread is also necessary: if $(\mu_n)$ is tight, then there exists an increasing sequence $(R_j)$ with $R_j\uparrow+\infty$ such that $\sup_n\mu_n(\mathbb R\setminus [-R_j,R_j])\leqslant j^{-3}$. Define for $x \in [R_j,R_{j+1})\cup (-R_{j+1},-R_j]$, $f(x):=j$. 
Then $$\int f(x)\mathrm d\mu_n\leqslant \mu[-R_1,R_1]+\sum_{j\geqslant 1}j\cdot \mu_n\left(\left[R_j,R_{j+1}\right)\cup \left(-R_{j+1},R_j\right]\right)<+\infty.$$
However, I am not sure that this is simpler to check than the usual definition.